# Access a router remotely using another router

Tags: wireless-networking, router, ftp

I have a task in my hand.

I have Bullet 2HP router that is directly connected to my computer and a Linksys router which has a Trednet antenna and is connected to another computer.

I have to perform a basic a ftp operation to access a folder from the computer connected to the Linksys that is broadcasting that particular folder. I know the IP address of the linksys router and the password to access the router. I also have the login credentials for the ftp request.

I have been researching on this for a while but all the methods I found do this over internet access. My problem is that I don't have internet access. 
Is there any other way to perform such a task?

Comment: How are the two routers connected to each other (if at all)? Is the other computer connected to the Linksys router located off-site? If so, then you'll ultimately need an internet connection to reach it.

Comment: No the routers are not connected. But I want to establish a connection between the routers for the ftp request. The other computer connected to linksys is within the range of the Bullet router.

Comment: Can you connect the both routers with an ethernet cable, or do you have to connect them with Wifi?

Comment: No I can't connect with an ethernet cable. I want to connect with wifi only.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to create a wireless bridge. This is done by setting one wireless devices as an "Access Point" and the other as a "Station Bridge" that connects to the Access Point bridging the connection. Not all wireless devices allow you to do this.

Depending on how far away the computers are can effect if you can make the connection.  (Across the your home vs across a street.) I have used inexpensive Mikrotik (https://mikrotik.com/products/group/wireless-for-home-and-office) Wireless Access Points to do this in a few places where we could not run a wire, so one of the AP's is in Station Bridge mode that connects to our normal WiFi Access Points (CPE is also the term they use for the wireless device that is connecting to form a bridge).

If you are trying to do it longer distances (across the street, 1-15 Miles, next town over), you will need external directional antenna radio combinations, that would mount outside and have line of sight, to make a wireless bridge.

In short see if you can set one wireless device to station mode, and the other keep as an access point, have the station device connect to the access point the same way your phone or laptop would connect using a pre shared key.